# compare collection values with returned values from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, arrays, collections

I have the following class:

```
    public class players
    {
        public void LottoDraw(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var connectionstring = "Server=C;Database=lotto;User Id=lottoadmin;Password=password;";


            using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))  // Create connection with automatic disposal
            {
                con.Open();

                // Create new DataTable
                DataTable player = new DataTable();
                {
                    // Create new DataAdapter
                    using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 1 LOTTOID, VAL0, VAL1, VAL2, VAL3, VAL4, VAL5 FROM tblLotto ORDER BY NEWID()", con))
                    {
                        // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
                        a.Fill(player);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        public int val0, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6;
        public IEnumerable<int> Numbers
        {
            get
            {
                return new[] { val0, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6 };
            }
        }

    }
}
```

It will return a random row from the database with some Lotto numbers. The values will then be put into a collection.

I then want to use some Linq to compare the winning numbers with what is drawn.

```
public void LottoWinners(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Dictionary<int, int> number = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            Random generator = new Random();
            while (number.Count < 1)
            {
                number[generator.Next(1, 49)] = 1;
            }

            string[] lotto = number.Keys.OrderBy(n => n).Select(s => s.ToString()).ToArray();

            var winners = players.
                Where(Lotto => Lotto.Players.Numbers.Intersect(lotto).Count() >= 3);

            //write some logic to find out who has 3 match numbers 
            //and assign there ticket to the winners table tblWinners

        }
```

However i get an error:

**'Lotto.players' does not contain a definition for 'Where'**

I already have: `using System.Linq;` in all my files!

Comment: I am assuming, because you did not post all of your code, that you have a namespace named `Lotto` and you are also using the term `Lotto` in the lambda expression of the `Where`. I would recommend you change the lambda expression to something like `Where(l => l.Players.Numbers.Intersect(lotto).Count() >= 3);` just to reduce confusion of what `Lotto` the code is referencing.

Comment: Lotto is the name of my project.

Comment: I am trying to compare the values in an array with the values in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use the `Where` extension method against the `players` class. `Where` operates against a collection that implements `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Good answer, you beat me by just a hair. LOL

Answer (score 1):

`Lotto.players` is a class and it is correctly informing you that there is no extension method named `Where` on the `Lotto.players` class. The `IEnumerable<int> Numbers` property would allow for the use of `Where` though.

Comment: I dont understand why i cant call `lotto` as this is the name of my array.

Comment: `string[] lotto = number.Keys.OrderBy(n...` - thats my array. But then also in my class called players i have `public IEnumerable<int> Numbers`

Comment: The problem is you are trying to apply the `Where` extension method to a class, that will not work. `Where` will only work on an object that implements the `IEnumerable<T>` interface. So you could do `lotto.Where`, because a string array implements `IEnumerable`.

Comment: the question is where do i define the where statement? This is all confusing!

Comment: @PriceCheaperton - I suggest the [Getting Started With LINQ in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) tutorial on MSDN. If you do not understand what extension methods are, then I also suggest [C# 3.0 For Beginners - Extension Methods](http://www.ellogical.com/2012/01/c-30-for-beginners-extension-methods_29.html) blog entry.